# Retrieving params with sinatra on form submit. Params is undefined

Tags: sinatra

I am having trouble accessing params in Sinatra after submitting a form. This is my form:

```
function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/mix_addresses',
      //grab the inputs from address_section
      //data: $('.add_address_section .add_address_field').map(function() { return $(this).val() }),
      data: [1,2,3],
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        debugger;
      }
    });
  }
```

And this is my endpoint:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'jobcoin_client'

get '/' do
  erb :add_coins
end

post '/mix_addresses' do
  puts params
end
```

I'm getting to the endpoint, but the params are blank. Shouldn't it be `[1,2,3]`? Instead, it's:

`{"undefined"=>""}`

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked what the request sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues here :)

### Sinatra configuration

Main problem is coming from the fact that Sinatra doesn't deal with JSON payloads by default. If you want to send a JSON payload, then the easiest solution will be :

1. To add `rack-contrib` to your Gemfile,
2. Then, require it in your sinatra app: `require rack/contrib`
3. And load the middleware that deals with this issue: `use Rack::PostBodyContentTypeParser`

And you should be good to go!

*Source: several SO post reference this issue, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524020/sinatra-doesnt-show-post-data/21525582#21525582), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131763/sinatra-controller-params-method-coming-in-empty-on-json-post-request) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229855/posting-json-params-from-java-to-sinatra-service) for instance.*

### jQuery ajax call

Also, note that there might be some issues with your request :

1. You'll need to use a `key: value` format for your JSON payload: `{ values: [1,2,3] }`
2. You'll need to stringify your JSON payload before sending it: `data: JSON.stringify( ... )`
3. You'll need to set the request content type to `application/json` (`dataType` is related to the data returned by the server, and doesn't say anything about your request format, see [jQuery ajax documentation for more details](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)).

Eventually, you should end up with something like this on the client side:

```
function submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/mix_addresses',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ values: [1,2,3] }),
    success: function(data) {
      debugger;
    }
  });
}
```