# Sending Complex JSON Object

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, gson

I want to communicate with a web server and exchange JSON information.

my webservice URL looking like following format: `http://46.157.263.140/EngineTestingWCF/DPMobileBookingService.svc/SearchOnlyCus`

Here is my JSON Request format.

```
{
    "f": {
        "Adults": 1,
        "CabinClass": 0,
        "ChildAge": [
            7
        ],
        "Children": 1,
        "CustomerId": 0,
        "CustomerType": 0,
        "CustomerUserId": 81,
        "DepartureDate": "/Date(1358965800000+0530)/",
        "DepartureDateGap": 0,
        "Infants": 1,
        "IsPackageUpsell": false,
        "JourneyType": 2,
        "PreferredCurrency": "INR",
        "ReturnDate": "/Date(1359138600000+0530)/",
        "ReturnDateGap": 0,
        "SearchOption": 1
    },
    "fsc": "0"
}
```

I tried with the following code to send a request:

```
public class Fdetails {
    private String Adults = "1";
    private String CabinClass = "0";
    private String[] ChildAge = { "7" };
    private String Children = "1";
    private String CustomerId = "0";
    private String CustomerType = "0";
    private String CustomerUserId = "0";
    private Date DepartureDate = new Date();
    private String DepartureDateGap = "0";
    private String Infants = "1";
    private String IsPackageUpsell = "false";
    private String JourneyType = "1";
    private String PreferredCurrency = "MYR";
    private String ReturnDate = "";
    private String ReturnDateGap = "0";
    private String SearchOption = "1";
}

public class Fpack {
    private Fdetails f = new Fdetails();
    private String fsc = "0";
}
```

Then using Gson I create the **JSON object** like:

```
public static String getJSONString(String url) {
String jsonResponse = null;
String jsonReq = null;
Fpack fReq = new Fpack();

try {                                                
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    jsonReq = gson.toJson(fReq);                        
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonReq);
    JSONObject jsonObjRecv = HttpClient.SendHttpPost(url, json);
    jsonResponse = jsonObjRecv.toString();
} 
catch (JSONException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                }               
return jsonResponse;
    }
```

and my `HttpClient.SendHttpPost` method is

```
public static JSONObject SendHttpPost(String URL, JSONObject json) {

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);

            StringEntity se;
            se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));          
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                // Read the content stream
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
                if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                    instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
                }

                // convert content stream to a String
                String resultString= convertStreamToString(instream);
                instream.close();
                resultString = resultString.substring(1,resultString.length()-1); // remove wrapping "[" and "]"

                // Transform the String into a JSONObject
                JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString);
            return jsonObjRecv;
            } 
    catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Now I get the following exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value !DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
```

and the printout of JSON string right before I make the request is as follows:

```
{
    "f": {
        "PreferredCurrency": "MYR",
        "ReturnDate": "",            
        "ChildAge": [
            7
        ],
        "DepartureDate": "Mar 2, 2013 1:17:06 PM",
        "CustomerUserId": 0,
        "CustomerType": 0,
        "CustomerId": 0,
        "Children": 1,
        "DepartureDateGap": 0,
        "Infants": 1,
        "IsPackageUpsell": false,
        "JourneyType": 1,
        "CabinClass": 0,
        "Adults": 1,
        "ReturnDateGap": 0,
        "SearchOption": 1

    },
    "fsc": "0"
}
```

How do I solve this exception? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was a BAD REQUEST. Thats why server returns response as XML format.
The problem is to convert the non primitive data(DATE) to JSON object.. so it would be Bad Request..
I solved myself to understand the GSON adapters.. Here is the code I used:

```
try {                                                       
                        JsonSerializer<Date> ser = new JsonSerializer<Date>() {

                            @Override
                            public JsonElement serialize(Date src, Type typeOfSrc,
                                    JsonSerializationContext comtext) {

                                return src == null ? null : new JsonPrimitive("/Date("+src.getTime()+"+05300)/");
                            }
                        };
                        JsonDeserializer<Date> deser = new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {                           
                            @Override
                            public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                                    JsonDeserializationContext jsonContext) throws JsonParseException {

                                String tmpDate = json.getAsString();

                                  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
                                  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tmpDate);
                                  boolean found = false;

                                  while (matcher.find() && !found) {
                                       found = true;
                                        tmpDate = matcher.group();
                                  }
                                return json == null ? null : new Date(Long.parseLong(tmpDate));                             
                            }
                        };
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite familiar with Json, but I know it's pretty commonly used today, and your code seems no problem.

**How to convert this JSON string to JSON object?**

Well, you almost get there, just send the JSON string to your server, and use Gson again in your server:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Fpack f = gson.fromJSON(json, Fpack.class);
```

http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html

**About the Exception:**

You should remove this line, because you are sending a request, not responsing to one:

```
httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

And I would change this line:

```
httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

to

```
se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
```

If this doesn't make any difference, please print out your JSON string before you send the request, let's see what's in there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but when i send the json string to my server, i got this warning `org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject` and get `NULL` as response from server. any idea?

Comment: @bala How do you send this string ? Did you get the Exception in server side or client side ?

Comment: //Did you get the Exception in server side or client side ?//
 i got that Exception in client side..
//How do you send this string ?//
I update my question about that.. please see..and help me..

Comment: as you say I made changes, but now i got this exception.. `org.json.JSONException: Value !DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject 
at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111) 
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158) 
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)`
 I update the printout of json string before send the request, please see..

Comment: @bala - from the two exception stacktraces you posted, there is some (possibly hidden) XML content in your JSON string. Are you using a JSON object to convert the incoming JSON string on the server side? Post the full resource method (from the server side) to your question please.

Comment: @Perception //Are you using a JSON object to convert the incoming JSON string on the server side?//
I did not get what you say.. i make the request on Client side(in Android Application). I am not the control of Server side. I am using JSON object for receiving the Response from server. 

And I have a new doubt, the following URL is provide the webservice for me.. http://44.139.273.200/EngineTestingWCF/MobileBookingService.svc/SearchOnly
In API Document they are mention the JSON Sample Request format that is in my Question..
is this correct way i am going?? plese help me..

Comment: @bala - ok, now we are getting somewhere. Your current code does not show a JSONObject at all (so I just assumed server side). Two things, include in your question where you are getting the response from the server, and converting it into a JSONObject. Also, print out the response string from the server and add that too your question as well.

Comment: @Perception How you assumed server side? Actually i consume the webservice by making a request with  jsonObject parameter and expecting the response from server. So I think I am on Client side.
i am totally changed my question with my current code.. please see..

Comment: @bala - I'm almost 100% sure your server is returning you XML. Add an Accept header before sending the request - `httpPostRequest.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");`.

Comment: @Perception After adding
 `httpPostRequest.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");`
`httpPostRequest.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");`
this lines now i get the following Exception
`org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158) 
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
`
How do I solve this exception?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25420/discussion-between-perception-and-bala)

Answer (score 3):

To create a request with JSON object attached to it what you should do is the following:

```
public static String sendComment (String commentString, int taskId, String    sessionId, int displayType, String url) throws Exception
{
    Map<String, Object> jsonValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    jsonValues.put("sessionID", sessionId);
    jsonValues.put("NewTaskComment", commentString);
    jsonValues.put("TaskID" , taskId);
    jsonValues.put("DisplayType" , displayType);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonValues);

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url + SEND_COMMENT_ACTION);

    AbstractHttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8"));
    entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
    post.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    return getContent(response);    
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, instead of using `StringEntity`. +1.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood you want to make a request to the server using the JSON you have created, you can do something like this:

```
URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    String urlParameters ="json="+ jsonSend;  
    try {
      url = new URL(targetURL);
      connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
           "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  
      DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                  connection.getOutputStream ());
      wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
      wr.flush ();
      wr.close ();

      InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      String line;
      StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
      while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
      }
      rd.close();
      return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;

    } finally {

      if(connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect(); 
      }
    }
  }
```